# How do I install Plague Inc on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, games

How do I install the Plague Inc game on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like the game works natively in Linux, so just buy it in Steam?

Comment: FYI If you own the Win version on Steam, you own the Linux version too ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can buy the game [here](http://store.steampowered.com/app/246620/) on steam.

This are the minimum requirements:

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 & Steam OS 1.59/  Processor: 2.0 GHz Dual Core
Processor/  Memory: 2 GB RAM/  Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000 or
greater/  Storage: 500 MB available space
```

Install steam with:

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

[image]